# Timeout an HTTTP request properly in angular with a service worker

Tags: angular, rxjs, service-worker, angular-service-worker

As part of a new feature my team is adding, I was asked that when a specific HTTP Post request fails (When there is slow to no internet available), I will retry the request every X seconds over a total span period of Y seconds. For example, every 1 second in a period of 8 seconds.
This is the code I came out with:

```js
    return this.carService.saveCar(car)
      .pipe(this.isRetryable() ? retryWhen(errors => {
        return errors.pipe(mergeMap(response => {
          if (response.status === TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION_CODE || response.status === UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_CODE) {
            return of(response).pipe(delay(this.saveCarRetryTimeout)) // X seconds
          }
          
          return throwError(response);
      }));
    }) : tap(),
    this.isRetryable() ? timeout(this.saveCarProccessTime) : tap(), // Y Seconds
    tap((carId: number) => {
      this.logger.info(saveCarBaseLog.setStatus(LogStatus.COMPLETE));
    }),
    catchError((err) => {
      this.logger.error(saveCarBaseLog).setStatus(LogStatus.FAILED)); 
      return throwError(err);
    }));
```

The isRetryable() function just checks if we have both X and Y configurations set, so it won't affect the process.

After doing so and seeing that it works good both local and in the development environment, we uploaded the version. The next day we encountered a problem - In the preprod and prod environments, some cars are saved twice.
After an investigation I made, it looks like this problem comes from the service worker we have - whenever a full timeout occurs, the request itself timeouts, although the FETCH request associated with it is never cancelled, which causes a problem when the internet is just slow (the FETCH request eventually succeeds, and we don't get any indication about it).
I'm really lost on what to do here so any help is welcome!

I can't upload a screenshot of the network since it's a private network,
But in the network section in chrome it looks like this:

POST request - saveCar - XHR - 504 Timeout 
POST request - (ServiceWorker) saveCar - FETCH - 504 Timeout 
POST request - saveCar - XHR - 504 Timeout 
POST request - (ServiceWorker) saveCar - FETCH - 504 Timeout 
POST request - saveCar - XHR - 504 Timeout 
**POST request - (ServiceWorker) saveCar - FETCH - 200 Success (The problematic one)**

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of your indentation. Pretty sure your call to pipe doesn't have a closing bracket? Also your final catchError ends without a `}` or a `return` statement. Right after that, you have a dangling `return` and closing `}` that probably both should belong to the `catchError`. Does this parse?

Comment: @MrkSef Hey, I've added the closing brackets and formatted the code as JS. Sorry, it's my first time posting such code, so tried my best. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Looks good now 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

After simplifying a bit, here is how I understand the logic you've implemented so far:

```ts
class arbitraryClass{
  
  /* ... arbitrary code ... */

  arbitraryMethod(){
    return this.carService.saveCar(car).pipe(
      this.retryTimeoutLogic(),
      tap({
        complete: () => this.logger.info(saveCarBaseLog.setStatus(LogStatus.COMPLETE)),
        error: err => this.logger.error(saveCarBaseLog.setStatus(LogStatus.FAILED))
      })
    );
  }

  retryTimeoutLogic<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
    return s => !this.isRetryable() ? s : s.pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        filter(response => {
          if (response.status !== TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION_CODE || 
              response.status !== UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_CODE
          ) {
            throw response;
          }
          return true;
          
        }),
        delay(this.saveCarRetryTimeout) // retry after X seconds
      )),
      timeout(this.saveCarProccessTime) // error after Y Seconds
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is what happens when `timeout(this.saveCarProccessTime)` throws an error. It calls `unsubscribe` on the source then emits an error `downstream`.

This means that `this.carService.saveCar(car)` needs an unsubscribe method that can cancel mid-flight or even recently completed requests (due to how async stuff might order itself).

You need to look there.

... or

## Another possible solution

Never cancel in-flight requests. The server holds the single source of truth, always assume `saveCar` may still succeed if you've not been told `upstream` (by the server), that it has failed.

Just stop retrying after y seconds. You'll get another 504 Timeout and you can throw that to the consumer directly to handle however they decide (presumably the same way they would if `this.isRetryable()` returned false).

```ts
retryTimeoutLogic<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => !this.isRetryable() ? s : defer(() => {

    // The time when we stop retrying on TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION_CODE &
    // UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_CODE. After this time we rethrow instead
    const timeoutDate = new Date().getMilliseconds() +  this.saveCarProccessTime
    
    return s.pipe(
      retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(
        filter(response => {
          if (response.status !== TIMEOUT_EXCEPTION_CODE || 
              response.status !== UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_CODE ||
              new Date().getMilliseconds() > timeoutDate
          ) {
            throw response;
          }
          return true;
        }),
        delay(this.saveCarRetryTimeout) // retry after X seconds
      ))
    );
  })
}
```

Comment: I've noticed a problem in the second code block.
First, the if condition needs to have the logic of If the error is a timeout, and the timeout hasn't passed we want to proceed. With the current code, it will continue if either of them is true.
Second, this code doesn't serve the same purpose - if the first request sent takes A LOT of time, it just won't retry since I don't have any timeout. The main problem is the service worker's behavior on the timeout (Since the request itself is being cancelled).
Perhaps moving the timeout logic to the server side will be smarter?

Comment: Yeah, good spot on that condition. Also, yes, the second solution doesn't want to get the server to roll back a change mid-flight. If that's what you want, you need to implement in the server and/or create a considerablly more complex savecar service (with some kind of handshake). I don't see any alternatives off the top of my head.